# How to produce the same Group ID for like records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with an address and a date that I need a unique ID for each record with the same address and date.  Here is what I need it to look like:

```
     Address       |  Date    |  Group_id
     --------------------------------------
     12 address      1-1-2014       1
     14 address      1-2-2014       2
     14 address      1-2-2014       2
     14 address      1-2-2014       2
     12 address      1-3-2014       3
     12 address      1-3-2014       3
     13 address      1-4-2014       4
     13 address      1-4-2014       4
```

The problem is ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by Address, Date) gives this result:

```
     Address       |  Date    |  Group_id
     --------------------------------------
     12 address      1-1-2014       1
     14 address      1-2-2014       1
     14 address      1-2-2014       2
     14 address      1-2-2014       3
     12 address      1-3-2014       1
     12 address      1-3-2014       2
     13 address      1-4-2014       1
     13 address      1-4-2014       2
```

Also, Dense_Rank() returns all 1's for the Group ID

Ideas?

Comment: Can you post sample expected result for the data? It is not clear what values you want group id to return.

Comment: The first table is what I want.  Notice that the IDs are unique ONLY when the address AND date are the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of **Row_Number** you can use **[Dense_Rank](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/en/book_rank_dense_rank_functions.html)**

Try this

```
SELECT Address,Date,Dense_Rank() OVER(Order by Address, Date) 
FROM Table1
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I tried that one too.  The results are all 1's for the group id.  I put that in the question to clear up any future confusion with it.  Thanks.

Comment: @Min, Why you think that this query not satisfy to your requirement?

Comment: When I used Dense_Rank and partitioned it by Address and date the results were all 1 and not a unique ID for each like record.

Comment: @Min I don't see `PARTITION BY` in the answer. Why did you use it?

Comment: My mistake, Ive been at this for a while and I added the partition by without thinking.  Thank you everyone for your help, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @table table(address varchar(100), datecol datetime)
insert into @table 
select '12 address','1-1-2014' union all
select '14 address','1-2-2014' union all
select '14 address','1-2-2014' union all
select '14 address','1-2-2014' union all
select '12 address','1-3-2014' union all
select '12 address','1-3-2014' union all
select '13 address','1-4-2014' union all
select '13 address','1-4-2014'


SELECT Address,Datecol,Dense_Rank() OVER(Order by Datecol, Address) Group_ID
FROM @table
```